# How to convert columnar labeled data to json using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, command-line, jq

Suppose I have the following stdout output from an expression

```
 Min 1st_Qu Median Mean 3rd_Qu Max NAs 
  1.000 1.000 2.000 1.875 2.250 3.000       1
```

And the goal is:

```
{ "Min":1.0, "1st_Qu":1.0, ..., "NAs":1 }
```

Is there a **trivial** way to do this with bash? (also trying to limit dependencies, and would prefer to just cherry pick what I need using awk over adding any non-native linux dependencies).

Comment: (1) Do you need the code to read the headers? (2) If so, how is it supposed to distinguish between the spaces internal to `1st Qu.` and the space *between* `1st Qu.` and `Median`? Or is that actually a tab? (You don't appear to have a hard guarantee that headers will always have two or more spaces between them).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy got the hang of the R package manager, but, for practical purposes, I think this is very useful.  In this case, let's suppose we have tab delimitations between columns.  Or, better yet, no spaces: is it possible to associate the header name as "key" with the columnar value as "value" in a json object with a trivial command line expression?

Comment: In your example, columns are 7 characters wide. Is it always the case?

Comment: @mouviciel let me restructure it for easier manipulation

Comment: Now that you've edited it, I'm ~80% certain we have an effective duplicate already in the knowledgebase. [Edit: Found it!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following might count as trivial but it does not preserve the precision of the numbers.  It assumes the separator is the regex " +", but you could easily change that, e.g. to "\t" if the value separator is a tab:

```
jq -n -R '[inputs | [splits(" +") | select(length>0)]]
  | transpose | map({(.[0]): .[1]|tonumber}) | add'
```

### Handling multiple data rows

The following assumes a `jq -nR` invocation:

```
def zip(headers):
  . as $in
  | reduce range(0; headers|length) as $i ({}; .[headers[$i]] = ($in[$i]) );

def s2a: [splits(" +") | select(length>0)];

(input | s2a) as $h
| inputs | s2a | map(tonumber) | zip($h)
```

Comment: This is a better example of how to code with jq than I have seen anywhere.